# Does it make any sense to use rotation rate tensor for production estimation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

It seems to me many CFD codes in coding the turbulence models, uses the relation $\tau_{ij}{\partial _j}{U_i}=\tau_{ij}W_{ij}$ instead of using strain-rate tensor, i.e., $\tau_{ij}{\partial _j}{U_i}=\tau_{ij}S_{ij}$ for the sake of numerical friendliness, to estimate the production term $P_k=\tau_{ij}{\partial _j}{U_i}$.

Where $\tau_{ij}$ is the specific Reynolds Stress Tensor, it is symmetric. And $S_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}({\partial _j}{U_i}+{\partial _i}{U_j})$ and $W_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}({\partial _j}{U_i}-{\partial _i}{U_j})$ are Rate-of-Strain Tensor and Rotation-Rate Tensor.

I fully understand why $\tau_{ij}{\partial _j}{U_i}=\tau_{ij}S_{ij}$.

But it seems to me that $\tau_{ij}W_{ij}$ should be **ZERO**.

$\tau_{ij}W_{ij}=0$,

Because $W_{12}=-W_{21}, W_{13}=-W_{31}, W_{23}=-W_{32}$ and $W_{11}=W_{22}=W_{33}=0$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I assume by $\tau$ you mean the stress tensor, but could you make that explicit?

Comment: Yes, the product between a symmetric and an antisymmetric tensor is zero. My question then is where you found the statement that many CFD codes use this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Reynolds Stress Models (RSM) and Explicit Algebraic RSM you calculate exact production using Reynolds stress tensor and velocity gradient tensor.

However in RANS models we use Boussinesq hypothesis and use strain rate magnitude $S$ or vorticity magnitude $\Omega$, a scalar quantities to model production e.g. $P_k= \mu_t S^2$. Kato-Launder modification replaces one $S$ with $\Omega$ in an attempt to remedy large production in stagnation regions, so we have $P_k=\mu_t S \Omega$. Menter's SST model used $\Omega$ until model revision in 2003.

I think modelers used a lot of intuition in deciding which one to use, based on behavior of these quantities in certain regions. Therefore you may find $ \Omega$ more often in models tuned for attached boundary layers.

Comment: "replace __ONE__ $S$ with $\Omega$"? Then where and when did $P_k=\nu_T \Omega^2$ come from?

Comment: I have only secondary sources,it's possible I made a mistake. I'm not able to get the original Kato-Launder paper from 1993, if that proves to be the case I'll change it.

Comment: Here are some secondary sources: CHAM: http://www.cham.co.uk/phoenics/d_polis/d_enc/turmod/enc_mmk.htm and CFD-online wiki: http://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Kato-Launder_modification